# Pymongo / Mongodb Aggregate Tip

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of documents as follows:

{_id: [unique_id], kids: ['unique_id', 'unique_id', 'unique_id', 'unique_id']}

Although, each document has multiple fields, but I am only concerned about _id and kids, so bringing it to the focus (where _id being the _id of the parent and kids an array of ids corresponding to kids).

I have 2 million plus documents in the collection, and what I am looking for is the best possible (i.e. quickest possible) way to retrieve these records. What I have tried initially for 100k documents goes as follows:

-- Plain aggregation:

```
t = coll.aggregate([{'$project': {'_id': 1, 'kids': 1}},
                   {'$limit' : 100000},
                   {'$group': {'_id': '$_id', 'kids': {'$push': "$kids"}}}
                    ])
```

This is taking around 85 seconds to aggregate for each _id.

-- Aggregation with a condition:

In some of the documents, the kids field is missing, so to get all the relevant documents I am setting a $match with $exists feature:

```
 t = coll.aggregate([{'$project': {'_id': 1, 'kids': 1}},
                     {'$match': {'kids': {'$exists': True}}},
                     {'$limit' : 100000},
                     {'$group': {'_id': '$_id', 'kids': {'$push': "$kids"}}}
                    ])
```

This is taking around 190 seconds for 100k records.

-- Recursion with find:

The third technique I am using is to find all the documents and append them to a dictionary, and making sure that none of them repeats (since some kids are also parents)..so beginning with two parents and recursing:

```
def agg(qtc):

  qtc = [_id, _id]

  for a in qtc:
    for b in coll.find({'kids': {'$exists': True}, '_id': ObjectId(a)}, {'_id': 1, 'kids': 1}):
    t.append({'_id': str(a['_id']), 'kids': [str(c) for c in b['kids']]})

  t = [dict(_id=d['_id'], kid=v) for d in t for v in d['kids']]
  t = [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in t)]

  #THE ABOVE TWO LINES ARE FOR ASSIGNING EACH ID WITH EACH 'KID', SO THAT, IF AN ID HAS
  #FOUR KIDS, THEN THE RESULTING ARRAY CONTAINS FOUR RECORDS FOR THAT ID WITH EACH
  #HAVING A SINGLE KID.

  for a in flatten(t):
    if a['kid'] in qtc:
      print 'skipped'
      continue
    else:
      t.extend(similar_once([k['kid'] for k in t]))

  return t
```

for this particular one, the time remains unknown as i am not able to figure how exactly to achieve this.

So, the objective is to get all the kids of all the parents (where some kids are also parents) in a minimum possible time. To mention again, I have tested for upto 100k records, and I have 2 million + records. Any Help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I would personally like to go for aggregation but the time its taking it killing the idea.. so any help would be great for reducing the time.

Comment: I suggest you add a sparse index on kids field and rewrite the aggregate query as follows:

t = coll.aggregate([{'$match': {'kids': {'$exists': True}}},
                     {'$limit' : 100000},
                     {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'kids': 1}},
                     {'$group': {'_id': '$_id', 'kids': {'$push': "$kids"}}}
                    ])

Comment: projection creates new documents, especially if you are just renaming them. That means indexes of the original collection are not used. Are _id and kids in an index? Try running the aggregate without the projection at the beginning... does it help with speed?

Answer (score 0):

Each document's _id is unique, so grouping by the _id does nothing: unique documents go in, and the same unique documents come out. A simple find does all you need:

```
for document in coll.find(
        {'_id': {'$in': [ parent_id1, parent_id2 ]}},
        {'_id': True, 'kids': True}):
    print document
```